# Experiencing problems with Firebase Database Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started a brand new project. There is no data yet.
But i'm not able to insert anything because this default: `project-name= null` record is missing. You can [see in this video:](https://youtu.be/k1D0_wFlXgo?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX&t=161)

I'm not sure what to do:
[image]

I tried to set data using JavaScript SDK but the default permissions for read and write require authentication. SO i need to change the rules. But i can't access the rules either.
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks:)

Comment: clear cache of your browser, use another browser or disable all the extensions/plugins.

Comment: thanks @Wilik you are right, i have this: Privacy Badger plugin form EFF and it was blocking my firebase console stuff. Works now :)

Comment: @Alon no problem :) Can you post your answer and then mark it as the answer? so this thread can help anyone with the same problem

Comment: @Wilik i can, but i think is more fare if you post your comment from above as the answer. I will definitely mark it as the correct one. It was you - that helped me after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the browser's problem.

You can try to clear your browser's cache or disable browser's extensions/plugins that have access to modify all the data on the websites you visit.

Hope this helps :)